# Blower motor compatibility

Tags: hvac, motor

I need to replace a old blower motor which is now obsolete. That part number is (1150519). I need to replace the capacitor as well (1150060). I am not sure what motor/capacitor I need that is compatible with what I have.

My motor has white wire (common) black wire (high speed) red wire (low speed) two brown wires (to capacitor) and green wire (ground). I am pretty sure it turns counterclockwise. The only thing I have found so far is motor 92L22 but nothing on capacitor. Or do I need capacitor on new motor?

Again thanks for taking the time to help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I took the question to be more about what the critical specs are for finding a replacement.

Comment: How about providing a picture of the spec label on the old blower motor. That should show all the details necessary for the very intelligent people here to be able to figure out what you would need for a replacement. Then, once you know the specs, you can go find a motor that meets those criteria. Where/what brand to buy is off topic, but "help me ID the specs I need" should be just fine.

Comment: Also, are you sure that "obsolete" == "no longer available"? Even if they're not made new, if it was a common enough product, it may be available as a refurbished/remanufactured unit.

Comment: Unfortunately , the furnace / (and AC ) hat it served are probably not in much better shape.  Consider replacing the whole unit.

Comment: Can you get us good shots of the wiring diagram on the furnace and the nameplate label on the old motor?

Comment: While the intent may not have been a "shopping" question, it certainly got a "Shopping recommendation" answer!

Answer (score 1):

Go to supplyhouse.com, they can help. Click HVAC, motors, then Century. Go down the page to the motor with the SKU DL1036. It is the same size as yours, the same RPM, voltage,and HP (1/3), and is reversible. You can also ask them for advice. Sometimes, removing the old motor from the shaft is a lot harder that it looks. If you are not sure what you are doing or do not have the expertise to do the job call in a professional for help. And, while you are replacing that motor, clean the vanes on that "squirrel cage" fan blade. Take it out of the housing, clean the vanes and pressure wash the vanes also for a complete job.